# Polymer changing style with selector

Tags: javascript, polymer

How could I change the style property of the element via the $ selector. I can not find anywhere which property this selector exposes.

```
this.$.elementId.css('height', '200px');
```

this example does not work. I would like to change the height on-click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
this.$.elementId.style.height = '200px';
```

Comment: yeah just the second I posted I remembered it is probably just pure javascript selector

Comment: It's a map containing the elements from the elements shadowRoot and returns the same element as `querySelector` or similar methods would.

Comment: yeah, I was mistaken that is jquery interface

Comment: Fwiw, it's true that the `$` there can be confusing. It's meant to invoke the idea that there are _elements here_, but it doesn't have anything to do with JQuery.